# onblur function is not calling jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery autocomplete, I have done select event, after selecting results are coming but `onblur` also I want to fire same event, but it is not working for `onblur` Here is my code please help me to solve, for select event what ever I selected it is working and function is calling, same thing not able to work on blur, any idea?

code:

```
<!--Function for Auto Search------>
 <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--<script src="<?php echo CUR_URL;?>new_template/assets/js-auto/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->
<script>
$( function() 
{

    function log( message ) 
    {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo("#log");
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop(0);
    }

    function myfun( event, ui ) 
        {
            $("#log").html('');  
            log( ui.item ?"Selected: " + ui.item.value + " ID is " + ui.item.id :"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );

            var ids = ui.item.id;
            var values = ui.item.value;
            search_id_arr = ids.split("-");
            var formdata =  ({
                search_id   : search_id_arr['0'],
                search_name   : search_id_arr['1'],
                                speciality_name   : values
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo CUR_URL; ?>new_template/ajax_code.php?data=setSearch_id",
                type: 'post',
                data: formdata,
                success: function (data) 
                { 
                    if(data !='')
                    {
                        if(search_id_arr['1'] == 'specilization' || search_id_arr['1'] =='service')
                        {
                            window.location.href="<?php echo CUR_URL; ?>search_detail";
                        }
                        else if(search_id_arr['1'] == 'doctor' || search_id_arr['1'] == 'clinic')
                        {
                            window.location.href="<?php echo CUR_URL; ?>profile_detail";
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    $("#search_key").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo CUR_URL ;?>new_template/ajax_code.php",
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 2,
        select: myfun,
        blur:myfun
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blur event not available in jquery autocomplete.
It supports following events only.

- change
- close
- create
- focus
- open
- response
- search
- select

Ref: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

So,  you may need to attach blur event separately. 
Example 
`$("#select option").blur(function(){
    myfun();
});`